# Android widget : Method call when button onclick in widget

Tags: android, android-widget

since I was new to android widgets , I have trouble with calling a my method which is for performing the data gathering from web service from my Appwidget.  here is my code is,

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
   this.context=context;

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);

    // LAUNCHING PENDING INTENTS FOR CLICKS
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wid_refresh, pendingMsgIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, getServerData(context));

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}
```

and  buttonPressed(Context)  is my method. defined as,

```
protected PendingIntent buttonPressed(Context context) {
    Log.i("buttonPressed","called");

    Intent active = new Intent(context, MainWidget.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
}
```

and my manifest file as,

```
 <receiver android:name=".MainWidget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

Note this :  **I can refresh my widget when click the button but I could not able call the  method named buttonPressed()**

please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

onreceive method is,

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("onreceive","called");
    this.context=context;
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
//  QuotesApp appState = ((QuotesApp) context.getApplicationContext());
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER))
     {

    } 
    // server data processing here.
            mponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MainWidget.class);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_project,project_hrs);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_activity,activity_time);


    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

I get the Log that I placed in first line of onReceive when every time I click the button.

Comment: You are saying that you can refresh the widget when you click on button it means getServerData(Context context) is working then what you mean by "I could not able call the method named getServerData()" ?

Comment: @vipul , It called only for the first time the widget loads, not on clicking the button then'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722517/android-widget-button-on-press-event?rq=1 please go through this link

Comment: I think there is no onclick event in AppWidget

Comment: Can you please show your onRecive method?